# How to fade screw modifier into cylinder without applying?

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

I'm trying to make a screw with the screw modifier.

[image]

It's important that I use the screw modifier because I want to procedurally modify the angle of the threads for animation.

I want the bottom of the screw modifier to look more natural/closer to how it actually looks in reality.

Right now it just looks like the screw modifier abruptly stops, and I'd like it to finish in the same way it finishes with real screws (I don't know how cause I can't quite find a clear reference online).

How can I make it more natural? Would it just be a fade into the cylinder? If so how would I do that without applying the modifier?

Comment: Probably best to do it how they're defined in real ones, with effectively a Boolean operator : The threads only exist within the domain already defined by the bolt profile, with a taper at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider fading the screw into the cylinder as an acceptable solution, you could achieve that using a lattice modifier after the screw modifier to deform the lowest turn of the screw so that it disappears in the cylinder. But I don’t know if it would be convenient for the animation you want to do with the angle of the treads. I tried to scale down in the X&Y direction the 4 lowest lattice points in order to reduce the diameter of the lowest turn but I got a better looking result when instead I just pushed 2 lattice points to make the screw end disappear in the cylinder.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[Edit: I order to avoid deforming the penultimate turn I better had set the lattice W points count to 8 or 9 and interpolation to Linear]